# htaccess redirect all liks but specific ones

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

how can I do this in htaccess

I have

```
/main_dir/([a-z-]+)/dir1 - this should remain as it is
/main_dir/([a-z-]+)/dir2 - this should remain as it is
/main_dir/([a-z-]+)/dir2/UQ13A -this should remain as it is
```

but

```
/main_dir/([a-z-]+)/UQ13A -should take me to /main_dir/$1/dir2/UQ13A
```

UQ13A - can be any string containing [a-zA-Z0-9-]

I am not so familiar with negative lookahead, lookbehind

for now I have something like

```
/main_dir/([a-z-]+)/(?!(dir1|dir2)) /main_dir/$1/dir2/$2
```

which is not working

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^main_dir/([a-z-]+)/(?!(?:dir1|dir2)/)(.+)$ /main_dir/$1/dir2/$2 [L,NC]
```